# MySQL: Joining three tables and grouping one column

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I'm an amateur on SQL. Here it is the example. From this three tables I would like to know how is called the teacher who makes more money with the classes:

Table1:

```
LessonName        TeacherID
Maths              3
Biology            2
Biology            1
Geology            1
```

Table2:

```
Lesson    PricePerClass
Maths         200
Biology       100
Geology       150
```

Table3:

```
IDTeacher  TeacherName
1          Mike
2          John
3          Lauren
```

My main problem is that I don't know how to deal with the repeated values from the first table when I'm doing the triple join.

So far "I've made" this:

```
select IDTeacher, PricePerClass
from Table1 as T1 
inner join Table2 as T2 on t1.LessonName = t2.Lesson
inner join Table3 as T3 on t1.TeacherId = t3.idTeacher
...
```

And I don't know how to keep going. I will have to group the t1.LessonName but every time I try to do it I get syntax errors. As you can see I'm pretty lost.

EDIT: My expected result would be something like:

```
IDTeacher   TotalRevenue
1           250
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I just updated my expected result, it would be a table with the teacher name or id and the total revenue of the teacher that makes more money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join the tables, group by teacher to aggregate and get the top row after you sort by the total descending:

```
select t3.IDTeacher, sum(t2.PricePerClass) TotalRevenue
from Table3 t3 
inner join Table1 as t1 on t1.TeacherId = t3.IDTeacher
inner join Table2 as t2 on t2.Lesson = t1.LessonName
group by t3.IDTeacher 
order by TotalRevenue desc limit 1
```

Note that this query does not return ties, if any.

Comment: Thanks very much! Now I understand it better. And by curiosity, If i would like to get who got more revenue than X person, how could I do it?

Comment: This is different question/requirement. Take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t3.IDTeacher, t3.TeacherName, sum(t2.PricePerClass) from table1 t1
inner join table3 t3 on t1.TeacherID = t3.IDTeacher
inner join table2 t2 on t1.Lessonname = t2.Lesson
group by t3.TeacherName
order by sum(t2.PricePerClass) desc limit 1;
```